# Executing Linux command in PHP on button click

Tags: php, linux, button, exec

I have created a php file on my Ubuntu server that should collect all data from an HTML form and POST them back to my server. I want the data to be inserted into a file that is located on the server. The command i want to do this with is:

```
$command = 'sudo -- sh -c "echo '.$data.' >> /path/to/file';
$executecommand = exec($command);
```

When I click the button on my php page, the command I showed here should be executed on the server and insert the data into the file.

As i am quite new to server side scripting and as I haven't found a simple solution for this I would like to know how this can be done.

Comment: Please don't do that. You will regret... and is that a "sudo"??? Are you sure you know what you are actually doing?

Comment: Execute commands from PHP is always not good idea, instad you can do it by `file_put_contents('/path/to/file', $data, FILE_APPEND)`